# Covered vs Noncovered Index & CRUD stored procedures question

Tags: sql-server, index, index-tuning

I have what is a very simple question for most here I am sure. I would like to point out while i can run a query with the statistics on and get the answer, I would very much like an "under the hood" explanation. I have 3 tables, for the sake of the question I am going to remove some of the irrelevant columns. I also have a simple CRUD stored procedure that operates on these three tables. The indexing portion of the question sort of transitions into the stored procedure part.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.UserProfile
(
    [UserID] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL

    CONSTRAINT [PK_UserProfile_UserID] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserID] ASC)
);
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.UserGroup
(
    [UserGroupID] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserID] INT NOT NULL, 
    [GroupID] INT NOT NULL,
    [IsActive] BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT((1)),

    CONSTRAINT [PK_UserGroup_UserGroupID] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserGroupID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_UserGroup_GroupID_Group_GroupID] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([GroupID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Group] ([GroupID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_UserGroup_UserID_UserProfile_UserID] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([UserID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[UserProfile] ([UserId])
);
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_GroupID] ON dbo.UserGroup(GroupID ASC); 
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_UserID] ON dbo.UserGroup(UserID ASC);  

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Group] 
(
    [GroupID] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [PropertyID] INT NOT NULL,
    [GroupName] NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Group_GroupID ]
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([GroupID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Group_PropertyID_Property_PropertyID] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([PropertyID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Property] ([PropertyID]) 
);
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Group_PropertyID]
ON [dbo].[Group]([PropertyID] ASC);
GO
```

Indexing question: on the `dbo.UserGroup` table and the others for arguments sake would it be better to create the index as covered index including the columns instead of having separate indexes?

In relation to this stored procedure I have inherited:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertOrUpdateUG]
    @UserID         INT,
    @GroupID        INT,
    @IsActive BIT,
    @PropertyID     INT,
    @ErrorTypeID INTEGER OUTPUT
AS 
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON

    SELECT @ErrorTypeID = 0

    DECLARE @SQLError INTEGER = 0
    DECLARE @RowCount INTEGER = 0
    DECLARE @ReturnCode INTEGER = 0 
    DECLARE @UserGroupID INT=0  
    DECLARE @UTCNow DATETIME = GETUTCDATE()
    DECLARE @StoredProcedureID INTEGER = 9060

BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT UserGroup.UserGroupID 
               FROM UserGroup 
               INNER JOIN [Group] ON UserGroup.GroupID = [Group].GroupID 
               WHERE [Group].PropertyID = @PropertyID 
                 AND UserGroup.UserID = @UserID)
    BEGIN
        SET @UserGroupID = (SELECT UserGroup.UserGroupID 
                            FROM UserGroup 
                            INNER JOIN [Group] ON UserGroup.GroupID = [Group].GroupID 
                            WHERE [Group].PropertyID = @PropertyID 
                              AND UserGroup.UserID = @UserID)
        IF (@GroupID = 0)
            UPDATE [UserGroup]
            SET IsActive = @IsActive
            WHERE UserGroupID = @UserGroupID
        ELSE
            UPDATE [UserGroup]
            SET GroupID = @GroupID,
                IsActive = @IsActive
            WHERE UserGroupID = @UserGroupID
        END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF (@GroupID != 0)
        BEGIN
            INSERT [UserGroup] (UserID, GroupID, IsActive)
            VALUES (@UserID, @GroupID, @IsActive)
        END
    END
END

SELECT @SQLError = @@ERROR,
       @RowCount = @@ROWCOUNT

IF (@ErrorTypeID = 0) AND (@UserGroupID IS NULL) 
BEGIN
    SELECT @ErrorTypeID = @StoredProcedureID + 2 -- Player Not Found
END
END
```

The second question in relation to the stored procedure itself. I clearly do not like the idea of updating a row value based on a join. I can also see this completely bombing out if there were a data issue that returned more than one row in the initial select and tried to assign it into a variable. In the current setup, this "SHOULD" never happen but I don't like should. Over the years many times what was not supposed to happen did. So I would like to be proactive and eliminate the idea of updating a row based off a value set with a join, I would also like to know what the best indexing schema for this specific stored procedure would be, and what would be some ideas on refactoring the stored procedure without using a MERGE to accomplish this task? As always thank you for your help and rather than just an answer, explanations why are always appreciated.

Comment: @max-vernon what was edited on this question? just curious?

Comment: Just tag changes.  http://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/123657/revisions